# Obtaining user access token in Facebook C# SDK (v6)

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-access-token

How to obtain an access token from the user using Facebook C# SDK (v6). How to use the FacebookOAuth class and what are the available properties and functions for this class. Also, after authentication, how to access basic profile information like profile picture, about me etc.

Comment: The (Microsoft created) C# SDK has some great tutorials and examples (http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/documentation), have you tried those yet?

Comment: Yeah I tried those documents but they are outdated and the code isn't working with v6 of the SDK.

Comment: Actually, I should have linked to http://docs.csharpsdk.org/ which is the site MS link to as a replacement. Have you tried the tutorials there?

Comment: I even tried this but the documentation is not complete.... There are some gaps in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an updated article using v6. http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-First-Facebook-Application-v6.aspx